# Comparing contents of string array elements with names

Tags: c#, arrays

I have one method called "PopulateNameArray" and another method called "FindStudentPosition".

In FindStudentPosition(string name, string[] array), I have

int intLocation = -1;

In a loop I have to compare the contents of the current string array element with the student name. 
If the names match, assign the element number to intLocation
Once found, break out of loop

How am I supposed to do this? Since the parameter in the FindStudentPosition is a different array than where the names are stored, how can I get it to check that array in a loop?

---

```
    public static void PopulateNameArray(string[] names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*Names Of The Students*");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------- \n");

        int intNumber = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < intNumber; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter A Name: ");
            names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }        

    private static int FindStudentPosition(string name, string[] array)
    {

        int intLocation = -1;

        for ()
        {


        break;
        }

        return intLocation;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
private static int FindStudentPosition(string name, string[] array)
{
    int intLocation = -1;
    //loops through all array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++; )
    {
        //checks if array element matches name
        if (array[i] == name)
        {
            //displays message and stores position in intLocation
            Console.WriteLine("Matches Name " + i);
            intLocation = i;
            break; // break when match found
        }    
    }
    return intLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already implemented for you, with the [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx) method:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, name);
```

Or use the fact that an array implements `IList<T>`, and use [`IList<T>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w0148af.aspx):

```
// IndexOf is implemented explicitly
IList<string> list = array;
int index = list.IndexOf(name);
```

Comment: It must be designated in a loop though. The loop it is supposed to run through is only 5 names which the user inputs.

Comment: Check the documentation. `Array.IndexOf` will loop through the contents and find the index or return -1 if none match.

Comment: @user2824965: Okay, so if you need to implement this yourself, what have you tried? You'd need to pass the array into the method. I'm confused about where you're having a problem, to be honest.

Comment: mainly, i couldn't process how the FindStudentPosition method would find the names the user would input and then check to see if they are there.

Comment: @user2824965: Do you understand passing arguments from one method to another?

Comment: For the most part, but I am still trying to grasp the whole concept I must admit.

Comment: It sounds like that's what you should look into then. Stack Overflow isn't very good for learning the basics of languages to be honest. It's good for very specific questions, but I think you'd be better off with a book at this point.